# Removing Event Listeners from Ref based on the state of the Parent Component

Tags: reactjs, audio, event-handling

I'm currently working on my first independent project, a composer's portfolio. However, I've run into a perplexing issue while trying to implement an audio player.

**Here's the structure of my components:**

1. I have a parent component called Portfolio with a single HTML <audio> element, which is used to play all musical tracks.

Within this component, there's a [activeAudio, setActiveAudio] useState that helps to keep track of the active track (the track that is currently playing or paused).

```
function Portfolio() {
  const [activeAudio, setActiveAudio] = useState(undefined); // State
  const audioRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>();

  return (
    <div className={styles.portfolio}>

      <audio preload="none" ref={audioRef}> // Single Audio Tag
        <source src="" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>

      <div className={styles.trackListSection}>

        <AudioTrack
          index={0}
          link={mp3Src}
          ref={audioRef}
          isActive={0 === activeAudio}
          setActiveAudio={setActiveAudio}
        />

        <AudioTrack
          index={1}
          link={mp3Src2}
          ref={audioRef}
          isActive={1 === activeAudio}
          setActiveAudio={setActiveAudio}
        />

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. Each individual track has its own component called AudioTrack.

When a user clicks the play-button on a AudioTrack, it sets its specific URL in the src attribute of the HTML <audio> element located in the parent "Portfolio" component. And  updates state 'activeAudio' in the parent component - "Portfolio".

And AudioTrack displays a value for the elapsed time.

```
const AudioPlayer = forwardRef(
  (
    { index, link, isActive, setActiveAudio }: AudioPlayerProps,
    ref: RefObject<HTMLAudioElement>
  ) => {
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [mediaTime, setMediaTime] = useState(0);

    const togglePlaying = () => {

// if 'isActive' for current track is false, then
// (1) set its link as src in ref.current
// (2) reload <audio> by the ref.current
// (3) set isPlaying(true) and set activeAudio in <Portfolio/> Parent // Component as index of current track;


      if (!isActive) {
        ref.current.src = link; 
        ref.current.load();
        setIsPlaying(true);
        setActiveAudio(index);

// if 'isActive' is true and isPlaying === true then
// pause it by setting isPlaying === false


      } else if (isActive === true && isPlaying === true) {
        setIsPlaying(false);

// if 'isActive' is false and isPlaying === false
// then it means it's paused, so resume it by setIsPlaying(true);

      } else if (isActive === true && isPlaying === false) {
        setIsPlaying(true);
      }

      isPlaying ? ref.current.pause() : ref.current.play();
    };

    useEffect(() => {

// if isActive for current track is false
// but isPlaying === true, then it means
// a user want to play another track,
// so we set isPlaying to false and remove listener from ref.current

      if (isActive === false && isPlaying === true) {
        setIsPlaying(false);
        ref.current.removeEventListener("timeupdate", onTimeUpdate);
      } else {
    

// if isActive for current track is true
// then user want to play this track, 
// so we add listener on ref.current

        ref.current.addEventListener("timeupdate", onTimeUpdate);
      }
    }, [isActive, isPlaying]);

    const onTimeUpdate = () => {
      setMediaTime(ref.current.currentTime);
    };

    return (
      <div className={styles.playerContainer}>
        <p>{`${isPlaying}`}</p>
        <button className={styles.playButton} onClick={togglePlaying}>
          {isPlaying ? (
            <img
              className={styles.playIcon}
              src={pauseSrc}
              alt="pause-button"
              loading="eager"
            />
          ) : (
            <img
              className={styles.playIcon}
              src={playSrc}
              alt="play-button"
              loading="eager"
            />
          )}
        </button>

        <div className={styles.timeValue}>{formatTime(mediaTime)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

**My objective:**

- When the "play" button is clicked for a specific track, I want to activate the interface elements associated only with the corresponding AudioTrack component.
- When switching to another track, I expect the control elements for the previous track to be paused or cleared. For instance, the component should stop tracking the playback time.

**Problem:**

When I switch to a new track, the control elements are properly associated with it. However, on the previous track, the playback time resets and continues alongside the playback time of the new track.

So for some reason, the useEffect inside the AudioTrack components does not remove the corresponding listeners when dependency changes occur and the if conditions are met.